# Unable to move cell up in uicollection view from storyboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, storyboard

I have added `UICollectionView`.I have also added the Cell in the `UICollectionView`.The issue is cell always getting space from top of **74**.On interface builder the y space column always shows the disabled value please tell how can i remove such issue?[image]

Answer (score 0):

Any given cell's position is determined by the collection view. You can adjust the cell's insets to increase spacing between cells and the scroll view's insets to position all of the cells in the scroll view, you can't directly manipulate a cell's position out of the box. When noting the position of your first cell you should also take into account whether your viewController has extend edges under top bars on and whether it has adjust scroll view insets on.